# WPF Menu with visibility permission

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a WPF application that loads a menu from an XML file, each node as a tag that identifies the user function. Each user has visibility permission that match against the tag defined in the xml file. I wish some help on simplifing that code since I's quite complex and from my point of view poor performing. Consider that the main menu is composed of main items and inside each there're specific areas function. If a user is enabled to at element at list the main menu node is shown otherwise not.

```
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MenuItemNode> RegisterMenu(IDictionary<string,Type> functions)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(); //I should get the module that invoked the base class

        string filename = GetFullFileName(assembly, MenuFilename);

        return Task.Factory.StartNew<MenuItemNode>(() =>
            {
                string xmlFileName = string.Format(filename);

                var doc = new XmlDocument();

                using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(xmlFileName))
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                    }
                }

                MenuItemNode menu = BuildMenu(doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/Node"), "/", functions);

                return menu;
            });
    }

    private string GetFullFileName(Assembly assembly,string filename)
    {
        var resourceFiles = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        return resourceFiles.First(x => x.EndsWith(filename));
    }

    private MenuItemNode BuildMenu(XmlNode parent, string path, IDictionary<string, Type> functions)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => parent);
        if (functions == null || (functions.Count == 0)) return null;

        MenuItemNode menuItem = null;
        string subPath = "Node";

        string name = string.Empty;
        string tag = string.Empty;
        int position = 0;
        bool forceVisible = false;
        string parameters = string.Empty;
        string group = string.Empty;
        bool showInDialog = false;

        if (parent.Attributes != null)
        {
            if (parent.Attributes["name"] != null)
                name = parent.Attributes["name"].Value;

            if (parent.Attributes["tag"] != null)
                tag = parent.Attributes["tag"].Value;

            if (parent.Attributes["position"] != null)
                position = System.Convert.ToInt32(parent.Attributes["position"].Value);
            if (parent.Attributes["force_visible"] != null)
                forceVisible = Convert.ToBoolean(parent.Attributes["force_visible"].Value);

            if (parent.Attributes["parameters"] != null)
                parameters = parent.Attributes["parameters"].Value;

            if (parent.Attributes["group"] != null)
                group = parent.Attributes["group"].Value;

            if (parent.Attributes["showindialog"] != null)
                showInDialog = Convert.ToBoolean(parent.Attributes["showindialog"].Value);
        }

        //parent item
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag))
        {
            menuItem = CreateMenuItem(name, position);
            menuItem.ForceVisible = forceVisible;
            //   menuItem.Group = group;
        }
        else//child item
        {

            if (functions.ContainsKey(tag))
            {
                menuItem = CreateMenuItem(name, tag, position);
                menuItem.ForceVisible = forceVisible;
                //menuItem.GroupName = group;
                menuItem.ShowInDialog = showInDialog;
                //menuItem.MenuParameter = GetMenuItemParameters(parameters);

                #region Multiple-tag
                if ((functions == null) || !functions.Any()) return null;

                #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                //todo: add-logging
            }
        }

        if (parent.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child in parent.SelectNodes(subPath))
            {
                MenuItemNode childMenuItem = BuildMenu(child, subPath, functions);

                if (childMenuItem == null) continue;

                int childPosition = childMenuItem.SortIndex;

                //This to prevent out-of-boundaries exception
                if (childPosition > menuItem.Children.Count)
                    childPosition = menuItem.Children.Count;

                menuItem.Children.Insert(childPosition, childMenuItem);
            }
        }

        return menuItem;
    }

    private MenuItemNode CreateMenuItem(string text, int position)
    {
        var item = new MenuItemNode();

        item.Text = text;
        item.SortIndex = position;

        return item;
    }

    private MenuItemNode CreateMenuItem(string text, string tag, int? position)
    {
        MenuItemNode item = CreateMenuItem(text, (!position.HasValue) ? 0 : position.Value);

        item.FunctionTag = tag;

        item.SortIndex = (!position.HasValue) ? 0 : position.Value;

        return item;
    }
```

And here's the MenuItemNode class

```
[ContentProperty("Children")]
 public class MenuItemNode : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string text;
    private ICommand command;
    private Uri imageSource;
    private int sortIndex;
    private bool forceVisible;
    private bool showInDialog;
    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isChecked;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.isChecked != value)
            {
                this.isChecked = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IsChecked);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsSeparator { get; set; }

    public MenuItemNode()
    {
        Children = new MenuItemNodeCollection();
        SortIndex = 50;
        SetCommand();
    }

    public MenuItemNode(String path)
        : base()
    {
        Path = path;
    }

    public MenuItemNodeCollection Children { get; private set; }

    public virtual ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return command;
        }
        set
        {
            if (command != value)
            {
                command = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Command);
            }
        }
    }

    public Uri ImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return imageSource;
        }
        set
        {
            if (imageSource != value)
            {
                imageSource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ImageSource);
            }
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (text != value)
            {
                text = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Text);
            }
        }
    }

    private MenuGroupDescription group;

    public MenuGroupDescription Group
    {
        get { return group; }
        set
        {
            if (group != value)
            {
                group = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Group);
            }
        }
    }

    public int SortIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return sortIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            if (sortIndex != value)
            {
                sortIndex = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SortIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public bool ForceVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return this.forceVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            if (forceVisible != value)
            {
                this.forceVisible = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ForceVisible);
            }

        }
    }

    public bool ShowInDialog
    {
        get
        {
            return this.showInDialog;
        }
        set
        {
            if (showInDialog = value)
            {
                this.showInDialog = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ShowInDialog);
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };


    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyExpression.Name));
    }

    #endregion

    protected virtual void SetCommand()
    {
        this.Command = FunctionMenuCommands.OpenFunctionCommand;
    }

    public string FunctionTag { get; set; }
}
```

In specific what I did is to process each child node then if visible I add it to the collection... do you see any possible better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whoever wrote that code clearly didn't know how to write WPF. In WPF, there is a much simpler option... just use the `MenuItem.Visibility` property to hide (collapse) `MenuItem`s that users don't have access to. Of course, you'd need some data bind-able security `bool` properties which you could then data bind to the `MenuItem.Visibility` property of each `MenuItem` via a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`. Here's a simple example:

```
<MenuItem Header="Some option" Visibility="{Binding User.Security.HasSomeOptionPermission, 
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ... />
```

If a particular user has the `SomeOptionPermission`, then the `MenuItem` will be displayed, otherwise it will be hidden.

Comment: Hello,Thats' a posibility ,but how can I hide the main menu if there're no visible items under him? With your approach I would see an empty node...

Comment: Add another security property that depends on the other relevant properties, eg. `set { return HasSomeOptionPermission && HasSomeOtherOptionPermission && HasYetAnotherOptionPermission; }`. That way, this property can be set on the top level `MenuItem` to hide it if required.